# Can I Develop Google Glass Apps Using the Mirror API Without the Hardware?

Tags: google-glass

I went through the Google docs for the Mirror API a few months ago and it mentioned that only developers with the actual Glass hardware would be able to test apps through the online sandbox.  Google took the Mirror API out of its "testing" phase last week.  Does this mean you no longer need an actual pair of Glass to test out apps or do the same restrictions apply?

Comment: Read from eBay Google Glass seller that, he no longer requires the hardware to test the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is partly correct. Anyone can add the Mirror API to a project using the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect) or [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console). See also [Issue #2](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=2) which was opened on this issue and recently closed by a project member.

"Testing" the apps, however, are still a bit tricky. Aside from reading the timeline using your same Client ID/Secret, you have no way to know that the card has been sent. And you have no way to know what the card looks like.

Using Glass is still the only real way to fully understand and appreciate the UX.